# replace row by dict and condition

Tags: python, pandas, replace, conditional-statements

here all
I have this DF

```
data={"col1":[np.nan,3,4,5,9,2,6],
"col2":[4,2,4,6,0,1,5],
"col3":[7,6,0,11,3,6,7],
"col4":[14,11,22,8,6,np.nan,9],
"col5":[0,5,7,3,8,2,9],
"type":["B","B","C","A","B","A","B"],
"number":["one",np.nan,"two","one","one","two",np.nan]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

this dict :

```
my_dict={"F":{"col1":2,"col2":44,"col3":0},"B":{"col1":0,"col2":11,"col3":4,"col4":50,"col5":np.nan}}
```

I want to replace the cells according to the dictionary (by type), only in cases where the "number" is NaN

I try this but its replay all the places that the type is "B" no consideration the "number" "NaN".

```
updatedf=pd.DataFrame(my_dict).T.reindex(df.type)
updatedf.index=df.index
df.update(updatedf)
print(df)
```

how can i add the condition of "NaN" on  "number" column?

that what i want to get

```
data={"col1":[np.nan,0 ,4,5,9,2,0 ],
      "col2":[4,11,4,6,0,1,11],
      "col3":[7,4 ,0,11,3,6,4 ],
      "col4":[14,50,22,8,6,np.nan,50],
      "col5":[0,5 ,7,3,8,2,5 ],
      "type":["B","B","C","A","B","A","B"],
      "number":["one",np.nan,"two","one","one","two",np.nan]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(da
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the update to `fillna`

```
updatedf=pd.DataFrame(my_dict).T.reindex(df.type)
updatedf.index=df.index
updatedf=updatedf[df.number.isna()]
df.update(updatedf)
```

Comment: thank you ,
but it's not work as i want too.
i edit the Q and now you can see What I expect to get.
i like to replace only when the number ==NaN

Comment: @matan Updated ~ :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean indexing to get only the rows where `number` is `NaN`, then use `fillna`:

```
updatedf=pd.DataFrame(my_dict).T

df = df.set_index('type')

df.loc[df.number.isna()] = df.loc[df.number.isna()].fillna(updatedf)
```

Comment: thank you ,
but it's not work as i want too.
i edit the Q and now you can see What I expect to get.
i like to replace only when the number ==NaN

Comment: The `.loc[df.number.isna()]` is supposed to do that.

Comment: I tried it but nothing changed,
Maybe there is a problem with the index?

Comment: maybe use `update` instead of `fillna` as originally in your code.

Comment: thank you, i use @BEN_YO ans 
but you too were very helpful